# Find avg ctc of a particular bu_ssu on basis of month using hire date

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have input data:

```
      bu_ssu                    ctc       hire_date
Customer Service & Operations   364000  2016-07-11 
Customer Service & Operations   52650   2016-11-04
Corporate Operations    151195  2008-10-01 00:00:00.000
Business Collaboration 155491   2010-06-14 00:00:00.000
Business Collaboration  177351  2010-11-15 00:00:00.000
Global Sales Group  138720  2010-09-27 00:00:00.000
Marketing & Communications  617902  2011-11-14 
Finance & Accounts  454000  2016-05-09 00:00:00.000
TCTSL   374000  2016-05-09 00:00:00.000
TCTSL   364000  2016-05-06 00:00:00.000
Global NW, Cloud & Data Cent Ser    167159  2016-07-11 

Customer Service & Operations   6280762 1995-04-03 
Customer Service & Operations   4032799 1995-04-01 
TCTSL   4273767 1998-02-02 00:00:00.000
TCTSL   1896148 2009-02-16 00:00:00.000
```

Required output:

```
    bu_ssu      month     year       avg_ctc
     TCTSL       05       2016       369000
   customer 
  service 
  & operation    04     1995       5156780.5
```

We need to calculate avg ctc of all the bu_ssu on the basis of hire month and year.

Example for tctsl we have hiring for 2016 05 then we need avg and we have 06 month so we need for that month also.

In output I have shown only two rows but in real it will be more acc to data. It is shown just for understanding purpose

I have not shown time for all, because I have lack of space but time doesn't matter. For all time is 00:00:00

Provide solution for SQL Server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want `GROUP BY` and `datepart` as follows:

```
select bu_ssu, 
    datepart(month, hire_Date) as month,
    datepart(year, hire_Date) as year, 
    avg(ctc) as avg_ctc
from your_table t
group by bu_ssu, 
    datepart(month, hire_Date) as month,
    datepart(year, hire_Date) as year
```